# Upgrading from Borland C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, upgrade, c++builder-6

We have an old project written in Borland C++ Builder 6 that we are thinking about migrating to a newer toolset, either a later C++ builder (probably the current one) or Visual C++.

I haven't had a chance to look at the code yet, so what do I need to look at before making the decision and wasting time on a futile effort?

The project is a command line application that uses sockets to communicate with the outside world, and does a lot of file handling using an internally written database. I would expect it to be using the standard Borland 6 libraries, but nothing particularly esoteric.

Unicode is an obvious issue, but I think I can guarantee that this application will never need to deal with this.

We may also want to migrate from 32 bit to 64 bit to gain extra memory.

Comment: *We may also want to migrate from 32 bit to 64 bit to gain extra memory.* For what's its worth, this is a common misconception -- although your address space is larger, you usually *lose* memory by going 64-bits.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This is mainly a matter of increasing the address space. The systems we run on have 32GB+ RAM, and increasing the maximum memory the app can use from 2GB would more than pay back the extra RAM usage of 64-bit pointers..